# Doctrine2 namespace object

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I've just started to work with Doctrine2 in Zend Framework (also just starting to work with namespaces) and am getting data out of a database. I'm getting the rows from the database and assigning them for the view with no problem, but when looping through the rows and trying to echo out a value, I'm getting an empty string.

```
<?php
  foreach ( $this->rows as $row )
  {
    echo 'id = ' . $row->id . ' <br>';
  }
?>
```

Result is `"id = "`

A `var_dump()` on `$row` results in:

```
object(My\Entity\Events)#227 (11) {
  ["id":"My\Entity\Events":private]=>
  int(1)
  ["_userId":"My\Entity\Events":private]=>
  int(1)
  ["_startDateTime":"My\Entity\Events":private]=>
  object(DateTime)#224 (3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(19) "2012-09-08 19:00:00"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(16) "America/New_York"
  }
  ["_endDateTime":"My\Entity\Events":private]=>
  object(DateTime)#220 (3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(19) "2012-09-08 20:00:00"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(16) "America/New_York"
  }
  ["_eventTitle":"My\Entity\Events":private]=>
  string(11) "Dummy Event"
  ["_data":"My\Entity\AbstractEntity":private]=>
  NULL
}
```

I'm guessing this is something simple I'm missing/unaware of and would appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your own `var_dump()`, the `id` property is private, so it cannot be accessed directly as you do in the `foreach` loop.

You must create an accessor method, for example `getId()` which will then return the value of `id` property.

See also http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: You are 100% correct. I intended to/should've marked them as protected. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to have been of help =) you might want to upvote/accept the answer then =)